# Angular 1.x autocomplete index issue

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a very simple auto-completion feature for an input field. I am using Angular 1.x on the frontend and PHP on the backend.

I populate the suggestions as follows:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'includes/modules/get_zones.php'})
        .then(function successCallback(response) {          
            return $scope.choices = response.data;  
        })
```

The backend PHP:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $country){          
    $reply[] = [
        'index' => $country['id'],
        'country' => $country['country'],
    ];   
}

echo json_encode($reply);
```

The frontend template:

```
<div class="choice" ng-repeat="choice in filteredChoices" ng-click="selectItem(choice.index)">{{choice.country}}</div>
```

This works but on selection the "choice.index" is passed as the the selection, in this case "index" is the value passed from the backend - the country table id. What I want to pass as the paramater to "selectItem" is the current index of "filterChoices". I have tried:

```
ng-click="selectItem($index)

ng-click="selectItem($parent.$index)
```

The value passed is always 0. I have also changing the index of the returned list of countries as follows:

```
$reply[$country['id']] = [
        'index' => $country['id'],
        'country' => $country['country'],
    ];
```

However when doing so this line fails:

```
return query ? $scope.choices.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
```

angular.js:14328 TypeError: $scope.choices.filter is not a function

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding `track by` to your `ng-repeat`? `choice in filteredChoices track by $index` and then using `ng-click="selectItem($index)`

Comment: @Michael yes I used track by as suggested, it returns 0. I believe the problem is in the structure of the array being passed by the backend

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself after reading about a bug with the $index ad how not to rely on it within ng-repeat. Although this wasn't the route cause of my issue it made me re-think my approach.

The reason I was seeing 0 for $index is because the suggestions which I was selecting from is a filtered list of the original full list, or a subset of it. Whatever the first suggestion is, whether is be x, y or z - the $index will always be 0.

The solution is much simplier than I imagined. Instead of passing an index or id as the parameter into my 'selectItem' function I just needed to pass the whole object, so:

```
ng-click="selectItem(choice)
```

This is the solution that the article I read alluded to!